# MongoDb Date query without using range?

Tags: mongodb, date

if i want to find a document created on a specific Day, until now i used  a range
from the first minute of the day, to the last minute of the day in seconds , sth like :

```
query":{"dtCreated":{"$gte":{"sec":1381356782,"usec":0},"$lt":{"sec":1389356782,"usec":0}}}
```

is is possible to to somehow find all documents where only the Day, Month and year equals "dtCreated" ?

in pseudocode like :

```
query:{"dtCreated":ISODate("2014-01-23")} <- i know that may not be a valid iso date
```

but what i want is to find all documents for one day without using lt and gt  ?

Sry for bad english and for any hints thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the aggregation framework using the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). 
Assuming dtCreated is an ISODate field, you could try something like this:

```
query = [
    {
        '$project': {
            'year': {'$year':'$dtCreated'}, 
            'month': {'$month':'$dtCreated'}, 
            'day':{'$dayOfMonth':'$dtCreated'}
        }
    }, 
    {
        '$match' : {'year':'2014', 'month':'1', day:'1'}
    }
]

db.mycollection.aggregate(query)
```

**Edit**: as orid rightly remarks, though this is an answer to your question (query for date without using date range), it's not a good way to solve your problem. I would probably do it this way: a range greater than or equal to today, but less than tomorrow

```
db.foo.find({'dtCreated':{'$gte':ISODate("2014-01-23"), '$lt':ISODate("2014-01-24")}})
```

Comment: nice one that works brilliant an was exactly what i was searching for   ! ! ! thanks a lot

Comment: @johnSmith Note that though the above code works fine, it's far from being harmless. Because it's using a `$project` first, it doesn't filter any document from your collection, though you really want to match a single day. Second, the `$match` can not use dtCreated index if it exists, because it doesn't using data straight from the collection. There is nothing wrong with your approach (`$gt` &  `$lt` query). If you insist, you can add an extra field for equality whose value is the day of year

Comment: I realized that. Unfortunately the date operators aren't available outside the aggregation framework